# Rotate ImageView when user scroll (ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-animation

I have ViewPager with 2 Fragments in my android application. The second Fragment(Page) has ImageView. Is it possible to twist(rotate) ImageView as in picture below when user scroll pages from one to another!

Thanks for any help[image].

Comment: Hey! Was you able to make this transition? I'm trying to achieve the same thing

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible. You need a class  that implements  the `PageTransformer` interface. The callback you have implement, receives two parameters. A view, results of onCreateView, and the position, which is a value between -1 (page out of the screen on the left) and 1 (page out of the screen on the right). When position is 0, then the view is centered. You have to hook in it, retrieve the ImageView from the view parameter, and call `ViewCompat.setRotation()` . E.g:

```
public class RotatePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
          if (position > -1 && position < 1) {
              ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
              if (imageView != null) {
                       ViewCompat.setRotation(imageView, angle); 
              }
          }
    }
 }
```

of course you have to adjust it to your use case

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answer but in my case rotate works only in one way and is it possible to rotate it gradually (maybe with speed)?

Comment: I mean that there is no rotate when I use this code. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: What does *there is no rotate* mean?